# How can I get the same result using group by and summarize function using power bi DAX?

Tags: group-by, powerbi, dax, calculation

I have written below code using `summarize-columns` function but I want to achieve this using `GROUP BY` function.

```
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
Mergetable[WeekDayName],FILTER(Mergetable,Mergetable[noShow]<>"true"),
          "TOTALDURATION", SUMX(Mergetable,Mergetable[MeetingDurationInHours]),
          "TOTALWEEKCOUNT", COUNTX(Mergetable,Mergetable[WeekDayName]),
          "DIVIDED",((SUMX(Mergetable,Mergetable[MeetingDurationInHours]))/(COUNTX(Mergetable,Mergetable[WeekDayName]))))
```

I have achieved so far using `GROUP BY` function but enable to divide the column `totalduration` and `totalweekcount` during run time.

```
GROUPBY(
    FILTER(Mergetable,Mergetable[noShow]<>"true"),
    Mergetable[WeekDayName],
    "TOTALDURATION", SUMX(CURRENTGROUP(),Mergetable[MeetingDurationInHours]),
    "TOTALWEEKCOUNT", COUNTX(CURRENTGROUP(),Mergetable[WeekDayName]))
```

Can anyone explain to me what needs to be done here to achieve same result as produced by `summarize-columns` function?

Comment: Are you looking for the average? Then you can use AVERAGEX..

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add DIVIDED column to your groupby statement, then cover all with ADDCOLUMNS.

```
 ADDCOLUMNS( GROUPBY(
      FILTER(Mergetable,Mergetable[noShow]<>"true"),
      Mergetable[WeekDayName],
      "TOTALDURATION", SUMX(CURRENTGROUP(),Mergetable[MeetingDurationInHours]),
      "TOTALWEEKCOUNT", COUNTX(CURRENTGROUP(),Mergetable[WeekDayName]))
,  "DIVIDED", DIVIDE([TOTALDURATION], [TOTALWEEKCOUNT]) )
```